# Как отразить numpy массив вдоль оси Y?

Tags: python, numpy

Например, вот такой:

```
xy = np.array([[[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [0, -1]], [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]]])
```

вдоль оси Y

Comment: numpy.flip() - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html вам поможет.

Comment: Что вы ожидаете получить на выходе?

Comment: [[-1, 1], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, -1], [-1, -1], [1, 0]] вроде так. если подробнее, то это свойство reflect в gdsii формате

Comment: [[-1, 1], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, -1], [1, -1], [1, 0]]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ожидаемому результату вам просто надо умножить второй столбец на -1:

```
xy[:, 1] *= -1
```

Comment: эти точки я ради примера взял, там смещение у каждой есть свое. не обязательно квадраты будут рисоваться количество точек тоже разное. в opencv знаю есть  функция flip. думал в numpy через что - нибудь подобное сделать